# How to restore messages when Messages in iCloud is enabled?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore, messages-in-icloud

How can I restore deleted messages when Messages in iCloud is enabled?

Historically one would just restore the iPhone to an earlier iCloud Backup however I have attempted to do that but since Messages in iCloud is enabled the deleted messages are not restored.

By paying for increased iCloud storage and having regular iCloud Backups one would hope that there is some way to restore these deleted messages even with Messages in iCloud enabled?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Messages in iCloud is used primarily to sync your Messages across devices.  Are these SMS or Messages you want to restore?

Comment: I understand. I just pointed out that I have Messages in iCloud enabled as it seems that once that is enabled messages are no longer included in iCloud Backups like previously hence the question of how to restore messages once Messages in iCloud has been enabled. I want to restore some SMS and iMessages.

Comment: Apple doesn't back-up SMS messages for all users in all territories due to local laws.  Do you have an older backup on your computer that would contain the deleted messages you want to recover?

Comment: Ok, forgetting SMS. How can I restore iMessages? Since they are no longer included in iCloud Backup once “Messages in iCloud” is enabled.

Comment: As @daniil-manokhin pointed out in the answer, 'iCloud Message' is for syncing your messages across devices so you can have access everywhere.  It does not mean your messages are stored in iCloud.  You appear to have a misunderstanding of what the feature actual is.  I don't know of a way to retrieve the messages if you don't have local backup copy of your device.

Comment: I don’t have a local backup, that’s what “iCloud” Backup is for. Where are the messages backed up? If they are no longer included in “iCloud” Backup? Before “Messages in iCloud” was a thing I could just restore an “iCloud” Backup and the messages on my iPhone would restore. What is the equivalent now?

Comment: [Apple states](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH26887?locale=en_US) "Note: When you turn on Messages in iCloud on a device, your messages are automatically stored in iCloud, and **aren’t included in your iCloud backup**."  When you deleted the messages, you deleted them from iCloud, too.  I think your only option is to restore your device from an old iCloud backup that had those messages.

Answer (score 4):

Messages are not included in your iCloud backup as they automatically upload to iCloud. After you restore to a backup you need to stay  connected to iCloud and your messages will download.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8491148)

> When you use Messages in iCloud, your text messages automatically upload to iCloud. They aren’t included in your backup. After you restore your device from iCloud Backup, stay connected to Wi-Fi so that your text messages can begin to download.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8414888)

> When you delete a message, photo, or conversation on one device, it’s removed from all of your devices. And since all of your attachments are stored in iCloud, you can save space on your device.​

If the messages are deleted it is not possible to recover them:

> Correct, my assumption (incorrect it seems) was that because the message history is now stored in iCloud, a message could be deleted from my device, but the message history could be accessed/reloaded again later. It seems that's not the case.

Comment: The messages don't download since they have been deleted. Hence the question on how to restore them.

Comment: @user316478 edited post

Comment: Surely it is possibly to recover them. I pay for iCloud Backup and this service is “Messages in iCloud” so surely the messages are backed up (somewhere) and can be restored, otherwise what am I paying for?

Comment: @user316478 you're paying for extra storage i.e app backup, photo storage

Comment: Yes extra storage so that I can use “iCloud” backup. This is Messages in “iCloud” so surely included in said “iCloud” Backup. How do I restore?

Comment: @user316478, the purpose of iCloud Backup is NOT to be able to go back in time. It is to save a snapshot of your iOS device in case it is lost or damaged. There is no need, for this purpose, for iCloud backup to include a snapshot of your messages if they are stored in iCloud Messages as that would be redundant and waste iCloud storage space.